# Traffic Analytics using k-means

Tags: machine-learning, k-means

I'm going to provide some (near)real time analytics (classification) of the network traffic inside of my cluster. All traffic is aggregated into "session" and consists of some number of features. I've chosen the streaming K-means algorithm from the Spark MLlib. 
So is it a bad idea to use the same data streams for training and prediction? 
If yes what is a better way to split the overall traffic stream into training and test data sets (considering that I want to classify each network session)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably collect multiple streams. Then from these get your train, test and validation sets, after which you later deploy your model the on-line data